Vuejs. Cannot set properties of undefined (setting)
data() {
        return {
            qty_to_order: null,
        }
    },

methods: {
        showQty(product_id) {
            this.carts.filter(function(cart) {
                if (cart.product_id === product_id) {
                    this.qty_to_order = cart.qty_to_order
                }
            })
        }
    }

When I call the method, I get an error. How to write cart.qty_to_order to this.qty_to_order (in data) ?
This method works
showQty(product_id) {
            this.carts.filter(function(cart) {
                if (cart.product_id === product_id) {
                    console.log(cart.qty_to_order)
                }
            })
        }


You need to understand how the this keyword works. The reason why it does not work is because if you use a function() {} as the callback the value of this is the window. If you use an arrow function, then you will get the correct value of this. Here is a great blog post about how the this keyword works in javascript.
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      qty_to_order: null,
      carts: [{
        product_id: 1,
        qty_to_order: 1
      }]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    showQty(product_id) {
      this.carts.filter((cart) => {
        console.log(this)
        if (cart.product_id === product_id) {
          this.qty_to_order = cart.qty_to_order
        }
      })
    }
  }
}
</script>

<template>
  <button @click="showQty(1)">show qty</button>
</template>

